# TypeError: Cannot read property 'ids' of undefined

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-context

Hi i have this error when i navigate to my DetailsScreen,i use react Context and i have there my two functions and ids.Please help.I also asked  ChatGpt, it says that problem can be that i dont wrap all my navigators with  but, i do.

error:
"
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ids' of undefined

This error is located at:
in DetailsScreen (created by SceneView)
in StaticContainer
in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
in SceneView (created by SceneView)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by DebugContainer)
in DebugContainer (created by MaybeNestedStack)
in MaybeNestedStack (created by SceneView)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by SceneView)
in RNSScreen
"

This is my code

DetailsScreen:

```
function DetailsScreen({ route }) {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const favoriteMealsCtx = useContext(FavoritesContext);
  const id = route.params.mealId;
  const mealItem = MEALS.find((meal) => meal.id === id);

  const mealIsFavorite = favoriteMealsCtx.ids.includes(id);// error happen there
  function headerPressHandler() {
    if (mealIsFavorite) {
      favoriteMealsCtx.removeFavorite(id);
    } else {
      favoriteMealsCtx.addFavorite(id);
    }
  }
...
```

favorites-context:

```
export const FavoritesContext = createContext({
  ids: [],
  addFavorite: (id) => {},
  removeFavorite: (id) => {},
});

function FavoritesContextProvider({ children }) {
  const [favoriteMealIds, setFavoriteMealIds] = useState([]);

  function addFavorite(id) {
    setFavoriteMealIds((currentFavIds) => [...currentFavIds, id]);
  }

  function removeFavorite(id) {
    setFavoriteMealIds((currentFavIds) =>
      currentFavIds.filter((mealId) => mealId !== id)
    );
  }

  const value = {
    ids: favoriteMealIds,
    addFavorite: addFavorite,
    removeFavorite: removeFavorite,
  };
  return (
    <FavoritesContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </FavoritesContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

my App.js:

```
function DrawerNavigation() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        ...
      }}
    >
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Categories"
        component={CategoriesScreen}
        options={{
         ...
        }}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Favorites"
        component={FavoriteScreen}
        options={{
         ...
        }}
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}
export default function App() {
  return (
    <FavoritesContextProvider>
      <>
        <StatusBar style="dark" />
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
             ...
            }}
          >
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Drawer"
              component={DrawerNavigation}
              options={{
                headerShown: false,
              }}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="MealsOverview"
              component={MealsOverviewScreen}
            />
            <Stack.Screen name="DetailsScreen" component={DetailsScreen} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </>
    </FavoritesContextProvider>
  );
}
```

and MealItem where i navigate to Details Screen:

```
function MealItem({
  id,
  title,
  imageUrl,
  duration,
  complexity,
  affordability,
}) {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  function miPress() {
    navigation.navigate("DetailsScreen", {
      mealId: id,
    });
  }
  return (
   ...
```

I tried all that ChatGpt recommend me to do,wrap all my navigators to  and etc. nothing hepls